# What is the best way to programmatically keep track of the active application on Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

I want to create a background application that keep track of the current active application (active window). I manage to get the active application by using `GetFrontProcess` but now I need to keep track of it so I can know when it changes.
I thought of two ways
1. Setting a Timmer and recheck the variable each time the timer triggers (Should I create a thread?)
2. Creating a dedicated thread, check the variable in a loop and sleep for a few Milliseconds after every iteration to avoid overhad.

Efficiency is important to me as this should be a non disturbing background thread. 
Do you think those methods are right? Any efficiency considerations? Would love to hear about different ideas that are more efficient.

Thanks for your help
Gil

Answer (score 6):

You could observe the `NSWorkspace` notification `NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification`.

eg:

```
[[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self
                                   selector:@selector(appActivated:)
                                   name:NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification
                                   object:nil];
```

and have a method:

```
-(void)appActivated:(NSNotification*) notification {
    NSRunningApplication* currentApp = [notification.userInfo valueForKey:NSWorkspaceApplicationKey];
    ....
}
```